# Создать полигон несколько полигонов заданного размера в метрах

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть размер области 100x100 метров, на этой области необходимо нарисовать несколько полигонов размером 10х10 метров с отступом друг от друга 2 м, чтобы они заполнили всю область. Как можно это сделать, если известны только координаты углов области?

Идея только одна приходит на ум - высчитывать через Excel координаты, загонять потом в JSon или можно как-то это сделать через Яндекс Api? Делал до этого через QGIS, загружал туда Яндекс карты и расставлял по схеме точки координат, потом выгружал в JSon, но это очень долго получается...

Comment: надо один раз расположить и все? или нужен какой-то инструмент?

Comment: Хочу сделать чтобы это было шаблоном, допустим буду задавать координаты углов области и чтобы по шаблону строились полигоны (по заданным параметрам, а это полигон 10х10 метров)

Comment: расположение внутри большого квадрата всегда одинаковое? он ведь без остатка не поделится

Comment: Ну получается, если крайний полигон будет выходить за пределы квадрата, то его не буду выводить и все, проверку можно будет сделать. Просто размеры внутри квадрата могут меняться (например, не 10х10 метров, а 5х5, или 6х10, это будет задаваться условием размера полигона. Но внутри большого квадрата (хотя это может быть и не квадрат - это будет зависеть от заданных координат) все секции одинаковые). В итоге получается сначала надо будет определить общий полигон, а потом внутри этого полигона расставить маленькие полигоны.

Comment: Еще думал через .solveDirectProblem прогнать и в цикле расставлять полигоны, но мне надо это сделать внутри большого полигона и не выйти за рамки него... Как-то так

Comment: Слабо представляю, какое именно решение вы ищете. Если известны углы области, то что мешает вычислить координаты математическим путем? Каких-то "волшебных" инструментов в Яндекс.Картах для вашей задачи, увы, нет.